# Interesting card game probability question

Tags: probability

You have three cards, two of which are the same value (suit does not matter in this game). For example, 9 8 8. You draw six cards in sets of two, and if either of the two cards in a set matches your original hand, it is good.

However, if both cards drawn are the same, it is also good. My question is: what is the odds/probability of having a good hand, and therefore getting a new hand (with the 3 new cards)? What about 2 good sets or 3?

In experience, it appears to be well over 1/3, since I have done hundreds of repetitions by hand, and my pile has consistently grown.

Also: What are the odds the two cards drawn match one from your hand? I presume 1 in 13^3

Comment: What values can the cards possibly have? The integers from 1 to 13?  Are the values equally likely?

Comment: Yes, 1 to 13, all equally likely. Just a regular deck of cards

Comment: Is matching with an existing pair also good?  For example, you have $8\spadesuit, 9\heartsuit, 9\diamondsuit$ and you draw $7\heartsuit, 9\clubsuit$.  Is that a good draw?

Comment: Yes. All we are looking for is two matching numbers in a set of three, where the two drawn can go with any of the three in the hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the following procedure, starting with a set of three cards:

1. Draw a set of two cards from the remaining 49 cards in a standard deck.
2. If any new set of three cards can be made from the existing three cards and at least one card from the two drawn cards, the hand is deemed "good". The new set of three cards becomes the current hand. If no new set of three cards can be produced, the previous hand persists as the current hand.
3. All cards not included in the current hand are replaced in the deck, and the deck is shuffled.
4. Steps 1 to 3 are repeated three times.

The first thing to note is that the probability of getting a good hand is identical in each drawing, hence the distribution for number of good hands will be binomial.

Letting $a,b,b$ be the current hand and $c,d$ be the draw, the five cases that yield a good hand are structured as followed

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {c = d} \\ 
  {c \ne d\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {c = a} \\ 
  {c \ne a\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {c = b} \\ 
  {c \ne b\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {d = a} \\ 
  {d \ne a \wedge d = b} 
\end{array}} \right.} 
\end{array}} \right.} 
\end{array}} \right.} 
\end{array}$$

The probability of each case (tier) is given by the probability of the rightmost expression in the tier conditioned on all of the probabilities leading down to the root of the tree.

Let the expression $xy|xw,\overline {yz}$ be shorthand for "the probability that $x = y$ given $x = w$ and $y \neq z$".

We can compute the full set of conditional probabilities in the tree (which turns out to be a formidable task) using the rules of conditional probability along with several "seed" probabilities that can be computed via first principles (I strongly advise you to check these for correctness):

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {\rm Probability}&{\rm Value}&{\rm Symbol} \\
  {cd}&{\tfrac{{20}}{{343}}}&{{p_1}} \\ 
  {ca}&{\tfrac{3}{{49}}}&{{p_2}} \\ 
  {ca|cd}&{\tfrac{6}{{2401}}}&{{p_3}} \\ 
  {cb}&{\tfrac{2}{{49}}}&{{p_4}} \\ 
  {cb|\overline {ca} ,cd}&{\tfrac{1}{{67}}}&{{p_5}} \\ 
  {da}&{\tfrac{3}{{49}}}&{{p_2}} \\ 
  {da|cb,\overline {ca} ,\overline {cd} }&{\tfrac{3}{{48}}}&{{p_6}} \\ 
  {db|\overline {da} ,\overline {cb} ,\overline {ca} ,\overline {cd} }&{\tfrac{1}{{24}}}&{{p_7}} 
\end{array}$$

From these we derive: $${{p_8} = ca|\overline {cd}  = \frac{{{p_2} - {p_1}{p_3}}}{{1 - {p_1}}}}$$ $${{p_9} = cb|\overline {ca} ,\overline {cd}  = \frac{{{p_4} - {p_1}{p_5}\left( {1 - {p_3}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 - {p_8}} \right)\left( {1 - {p_1}} \right)}}}$$ $${{p_{10}} = da|\overline {cb} ,\overline {ca} ,\overline {cd}  = \frac{{{p_2} - {p_6}{p_9}\left( {1 - {p_8}} \right)\left( {1 - {p_1}} \right) - {p_1}{p_3}}}{{\left( {1 - {p_9}} \right)\left( {1 - {p_8}} \right)\left( {1 - {p_1}} \right)}}}$$

and then finally $$p = {p_1} + \left( {1 - {p_1}} \right)\left[ {{p_8} + \left( {1 - {p_8}} \right)\left[ {{p_9} + \left( {1 - {p_9}} \right)\left[ {{p_{10}} + {p_7}\left( {1 - {p_{10}}} \right)} \right]} \right]} \right]$$

which gives $$p = \tfrac{{2653862119}}{{10594057152}} \approx 0.2505$$

The probability that you will obtain exactly $k$ good hands in $n$ draws is given by

$${p_{k{\rm\ in\ }n}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  n \\ 
  k 
\end{array}} \right){p^k}{\left( {1 - p} \right)^{n - k}}$$

Comment: Is there a simple way to figure this out for n decks? What if the cards are not in a continuous shuffle, but rather put into a seperate pile (shuffled when all cards have been gone through)

Comment: There's a way to compute it for $n$ decks. As for drawing without replacement, solving that problem is beyond my ken. The best way to figure it out would be through simulation. If you're interested in the $n$-deck with-replacement solution, let me know. It simply involves replacing the $p$'s above with different values.

Comment: I was interested in a 4 deck version. Also, is the .2505 the expected number of sets for each draw? If not, what is?  Kind of weird that such a simple problem has such a complicated solution